# VPNC cannot find device "tun0"

Tags: tunnel, vpnc

I am trying to connect to my work VPN with `vpnc`, on my chromebook with Ubuntu 12.04.4 (64bit).

I have installed vpnc, and when I run it, after entering my user/password, I get the following errors:

```
Cannot find device "tun0"
Cannot find device "tun0"
Cannot find device "tun0"
Cannot find device "tun0"
resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
```

Can anyone suggest why it cannot find this tun0 device, or how I should proceed from here? Do I need to install something such that tun0 can be found?

Comment: Create the tun device then bring it up: # openvpn --mktun --dev tun0 # ifconfig tun0 up

Answer (score 1):

By default VPNC uses an ifmode of virtual point to point interface(ie tun). But it also has another mode that you can use, virtual ethernet interface(ie tap).
Try using that, ie:

`sudo vpnc example.conf --local-port 0 --ifmode tap`